# JavaScript Stop Button for wmv

Tags: javascript, wmv

I'm trying to get a button to stop an embedded wmv when I click it. I've been searching for awhile now and I have tried a number of different methods, but nothing seems to be working. he closest I've come was from using the example on this page:

http://www.killersites.com/mvnforum/mvnforum/viewthread?thread=3883

However it only seems to work in Firefox and not IE. I really need it to work in IE though. Does anyone know a way to do this? I'd really appriciate the help.

Thanks in advance! =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've tested this in IE8:

```
<input type="button" value="Stop" onclick="javascript: document.getElementById('ObjectName').Stop();" />
```

Worked fine for me.